# how to convert this string to '380,00\xa0' to float,I get invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python

I know there is many questions as mine and I tryied almost all of them but no one of them worked

Here is what I have  '380,00\xa0' as a string  want  to convert it to float

But here is what I get ValueError: could not convert string to float: '380,00\xa0'

I tried `str.replace("\xa0", "")`

The length of the string is dynamique so I can't do `float(str[:5])`

Comment: Does "380.00" work? Is your culture set for comma as the decimal separator? Try `import locale; print(locale.localeconv());`

Comment: @Rup yes dont have problem with that! but Ineed whats after the coma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decimal separator for `float` is represented by the `"."` character, not by the `","` character. Hence we have to do:

```
>>> s = "380,00\xa0"
>>> f = float(s.replace("\xa0", "").replace(",", "."))
>>> f

380.0
```

Comment: this is really brittle w/r/t locales.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17815252/57135

Comment: @Joe True. I was just answering how to convert the given string. Generalise that on your own risk only. :D